# How to convert a text date into the short date format in excel

Tags: mysql, excel, excel-formula

I have a database of dates that I need to map to another table in my MySQL database. The format of one table is listed as:

Dec 01 2020

And the other is listed as:

12/01/2020

My plan is to take all the text dates from table 1, convert to short date in excel, create a new table in MySQL, then re-map them to the short date in table 2. How can you convert the text date in excel so that it matches the format of the short date (12/01/2020)? I have tried using text to columns and other date functions in excel but have had no luck. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to convert columns that contain dates in serial number, and then copy each column (serial number) and paste it in another column. You can format the new column(s) in the date format you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use REPLACE to place a `,` after the day number and Excel will then be able to convert it to a date.  Then Simply format it as desired:

```
=--REPLACE(A1,7,0,",")
```

[image]